sf project deploy start with --source-dir doesn't work as expected
When I run the command sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts --concise --target-org TRPRTL/Mikhail --source-dir sfdx-source/SharedBase, it deploys all components of the folder, instead of only changed components, every time I run the command. But if I remove the --source-dir parameter and run the command sf project deploy start --ignore-conflicts --concise --target-org TRPRTL/Mikhail, the source tracking works as expected.

How to make the command with --source-dir parameter work with the source tracking?
